# Pandas: groupby quantile with agg values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to group numerical values by quantiles and create columns for the sum of the values falling into the quantile bands. Here's a simplified, reproducible example:

```
    raw_data = {'female': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        'male': [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        'number': [25000, 34000, 48600, 22000, 50000, 21000, 29000, 36000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['female', 'male', 'number'])
df

    female  male    number
  0 0       1       25000
  1 1       0       34000
  2 0       1       48600
  3 1       0       22000
  4 0       1       50000
  5 1       0       21000
  6 0       1       29000
  7 1       0       36000
```

Essentially I'm trying to achieve this:

```
pd.DataFrame(df['number'].quantile([.1, .2, .3, .4, .5]))

    number
0.1 21700
0.2 23200
0.3 25400
0.4 28200
0.5 31500
```

But in this dataframe show two new columns. One for the sum of males who's number falls into the corresponding quantile band and one for the sum of females.

Initially I thought this would be a `groupby` with `.quantile([values])` appended, and then `.agg({'male': 'sum', 'female':'sum'})` 
This doesn't work though. Can what I'm trying to achieve even be done?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `pd.qcut` to create the groupings:

```
qs = pd.qcut(df.number, [0, .1, .2, .3, .4, .5, 1], ['q%d' % i for i in xrange(6)])
qs

0    q2
1    q5
2    q5
3    q1
4    q5
5    q0
6    q4
7    q5
Name: number, dtype: category
Categories (6, object): [q0 < q1 < q2 < q3 < q4 < q5]
```

Then `groupby` and `agg`

```
df.groupby(qs).agg({'male': 'sum', 'female':'sum'})
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, but is there a way to keep the 'number' column as well as per my first dataframe, so that the quantile value can be observed.